# MySQL - Syntax error when trying to insert strings/numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I get the below error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('text','text','text',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,' at line 4

when trying to run this SQL command:

```
insert into `table`
VALUES
    (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`,`col6`,`col7`,`col8`,`col9`,`col10`,`col11`,`col12`,`col13`,`col14`)
    ('text','text','text',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'text','text','text'),
    ('text','text','text',11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,'text','text','text')
```

**UPDATE**: I'm a complete moron, added col names before `VALUES`...

Comment: Your statement makes no sense.  What is `col1` supposed to refer to?  Is it a variable?  A column in some unnamed table?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: col1 is the name of the first column

Comment: Please vote it to be closed, I can't do it as there are answers to the Q already. Sorry everyone...

Comment: @fishmong3r you can close the question without any votes

Comment: @robert How so? It allows me to vote only.

Comment: @fishmong3r i never tried to close a question , but i see the option close under my questions , i thought i can close my question anytime

Comment: @robert No, you can't. You can only vote to be closed like others. Also deletion is only possible till there is no answer to the Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into `table`
(`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`,`col6`,`col7`,`col8`,`col9`,`col10`,`col11`,`col12`,`col13`,`col14`)    
VALUES
('text','text','text',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'text','text','text'),
('text','text','text',11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,'text','text','text')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into `table`(`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`,`col6`,`col7`,`col8`,`col9`,`col10`,`col11`,`col12`,`col13`,`col14`) 
VALUES('text','text','text',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'text','text','text'),
('text','text','text',11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,'text','text','text')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into `table`

(`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`,`col6`,`col7`,`col8`,`col9`,`col10`,`col11`,`col12`,`col13`,`col14`)

VALUES

('text','text','text',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'text','text','text')

,

('text','text','text',11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,'text','text','text')
```